# Insert error 1241

Tags: mysql, database, sql-insert

I have two MySQL INNODB tables 'student' and 'instructor'. They are analogous in almost every single way. I can add arbitrary records into the 'student' table, but not the 'instructor' table. Both tables have the same structure with ID as the primary key.

(ID varchar, name varchar, dept_name, varchar, field4 int)

I have tried queries such as

```
INSERT INTO instructor VALUES ('12345', 'name', 'computer science', 50000);
INSERT INTO instructor SET ID = 67890, name = 'Polson', dept_name = 'Bioinformatics', salary = 100 ON DUPLICATE KEY SET name = 'Polson', dept_name = 'Bioinformatics', salary = 100;    
INSERT INTO instructor (ID) VALUES ('12345');
INSERT INTO instructor (ID) VALUE ('12345');
```

while all of these queries work with the 'student' table. What is going on?

Here are my create table statements. My user has full permissions. Is there any status query that I should use to look for issues? Thank you!

```
CREATE TABLE `instructor` (
  `ID` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dept_name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salary` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `dept_name` (`dept_name`),
  CONSTRAINT `instructor_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`dept_name`) REFERENCES `department` (`dept_name`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `ID` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dept_name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_credits` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `dept_name` (`dept_name`),
  CONSTRAINT `student_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`dept_name`) REFERENCES `department` (`dept_name`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE department ( 
 dept_name varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 building varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
 budget float(12,2) DEFAULT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (dept_name) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

which contains a record Bioinformatics | DBI | 1000000.00

Comment: what do you mean `while all of these queries work with the 'student' table. What is going on`?

Comment: Insert works on one table but not the other    mysql> `INSERT INTO instructor (ID) VALUES ('67890');`
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
mysql> `INSERT INTO student (ID) VALUES ('67890');`
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec) mysql> `INSERT INTO student VALUES (67891, 'Polson', 'Bioinformatics', 100);`
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> `INSERT INTO instructor VALUES (67891, 'Polson', 'Bioinformatics', 100);`
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: @W4t3randWind: I try your query and no error happens..Can you give more detail ?

Comment: When I have create a new database, the error does not occur. In my existing database, I am receiving this error. The insert works fine for one table (see above, 'Query OK') but not for the other.

Comment: is there a trigger created on student table? that error doesn't seem to come from your query.

Comment: There are no triggers in this database. I know this is very strange. Are there any database status queries that could give more information about the status of tables?

Comment: There is a lot of bad with this design, first off the PK and FK should be ints not varchars. And, there are common attributes shared between student and instructor (name, dept_id, etc) why not an abstract `resource` table with a `role_id` column? To solve your immediate problem, try: `insert into instructor set ID = 67890;`

Comment: Once again, the relationships that exist between instructor and department are unique dependencies. And this syntax does not override the error. :(

Comment: Try this: `insert into instructor set ID = 67890, name = 'Polson', dept_name = 'Bioinformatics', salary = 100 ON DUPLICATE KEY set name = 'Polson', dept_name = 'Bioinformatics', salary = 100;`

Comment: I will add these syntaxes to the list of things that have been tried.

Comment: Can you create a SSCCE on http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?